# How to make Android application run in full screen mode?

Tags: android, android-emulator, master-detail

I'm developing an application on `Android, 4.2 (Jellybean)` for a tablet.

When the application runs on emulator, it normally contains the top and bottom ribbon/bar where it shows the battery and signal (in top ribbon) and 'back' icon and etc. (in bottom ribbon).

Question is, how am I going to make the application run in full screen where users are not allowed to navigate out of the application? In other words, I want to make the application full screen and also lock it on my application only.

FYI, I'm using Master detail flow for representing my items to users.

Cheers.

Comment: You can hide the action bar and rest but you can't lock the screen to your app. Simply pressing Home button would exit your app. It's standard Android behaviour

Comment: @Mohsen jan, what if I disable the button on the tablet too? is that even possible?

Comment: @Shawm, Not recommended but it may help (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6507063/home-button-disable)

Comment: Sounds like you want to run the app in [kiosk mode](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+kiosk).

Comment: `users are not allowed to navigate out of the application`. not possible unless you are set as the default launcher.

Comment: Thanks to you all for your comments. I'll try to do whatever I can and vote for the closest best answer.