# how to disable navigation keys in android programmatically

Tags: android

how do I disable the menu, home, back and search key programmatically in android, including the vibrate when those keys are pressed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162182/android-is-it-possible-to-disable-the-click-of-home-button - look at this post, it is just the same, and there are some useful approaces

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable the home button. The back button you'll need to override `onBackPressed()`, and the menu button shouldn't do anything unless you assign it an action.

If you mean disable these system-wide, I'm <strike>afraid</strike> glad you can't do that.

Comment: I'm thinking, like how the Video application of android disables those 4 keys by just pressing the power button. You can still watch the video but when you touch any part of the screen, even those 4 keys, it will just show you a lock icon on the upper right corner. So I guess it's possible since the video application can do it.

Comment: Well, I have a Samsung Captivate Glide and it came with a player named "Videos".

Comment: Maybe it's using an undocumented private API made by Samsung.