# Can I override the HOME key in an application writen in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, home-button

Hi I'm doing a "kiosk" like aplication using AS3.  I want to change the behavior for the Home key of the android phone. So that the public users can't acess the android operating system. So have seen that this question has already been asked a lot but haven't find a answer for it in AS3. This topic is very similiar to what i'm looking for

[Android tablet doesn't fire KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489958/android-tablet-doesnt-fire-keyboardevent-key-down/9491650#9491650)

But i really don't see an answer there that can solve my problem.

Most of the answers that i have seen are in Java.

I already had done it for the back button and it works perfectly.

So is there a way to do this in a AS3 application?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

May be you can along these lines:

```
if (Capabilities.cpuArchitecture=="ARM") {
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KE Y_DOWN, handleKeys, false, 0, true);
}
```

You can check the details here: http://forums.adobe.com/message/4075374

Comment: Thank you for your replay! yah i use something similiar for the back button but for the Home button it doesn't work it doesn't even fire the event. But i will have a look at the page to see if there's something that may work :)