# Android: prevent user from interacting with OS

Tags: android, kiosk-mode, cosu

I'm building an android app for a custom android device bought for a business point-of-sale. We want customers to use our android device and app without being able to interact with the android system in any way. This means no navigation bar with back, home and overview buttons, no notification bar or any other way to interact.

- I checked out some possibilities such as sticky immersive mode (https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html), but this still enables the user to swipe down the notification bar.
- I checked out if I could replace the Launcher ([Android: Prevent users from launching apps or using the OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815094/android-prevent-users-from-launching-apps-or-using-the-os)), but this leads to the same problems as above.
- I checked some other options to hide back buttons etc. ([How to set activity to fullscreen mode in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12388771/how-to-set-activity-to-fullscreen-mode-in-android)), but when text fields are clicked, the back button still reappears.

Bottom line, all of the solutions proposed still enable the users to interact with the operating system one way or another. How do I prohibit any interaction at all with the underlying OS, i.e. by only allowing the user to use a custom created back button? Preferably without having to root the devices.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2068084/6950238) question and answers. Especially [that](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html) link.

Comment: Read about screen pinning [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32377457/2910520)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set up Your Android device as corporate-owned, single-use (COSU) device. You can find Official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html) and tutorial with source code [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cosu/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0).

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out and accept your answer upon success :)

Comment: Wish You to achieve it ASAP )

Comment: Got it to work :-) it's a bit annoying that I need to run the dpm command before I can register my activity as a device owner, will need to do that for over 600+ owned android devices, but I assume there's no way to avoid this.