# Disabling android home button and notification bar

Tags: android, notifications, homescreen

I disabled the notification bar using the following code

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```

I used the following code to disable the home button

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{  
    this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD_DIALOG);     
    super.onAttachedToWindow();  
}
```

but when I use the above code to disable the home button, the notification shows up on top.
Can anybody tell me how to achieve both of these?

Comment: Why would anyone want to disable the home button?

Comment: I am making a lockscreen

Comment: I agree with Egor. The home button is there for a good reason, and should not be disabled. I doubt Android even let you for this exact reason. EDIT: Ok, i can see why in the case of a lockscreen.

Comment: The code you use to disable the home button doesn't work on API level 14+.

Comment: check this out...http://stackoverflow.com/a/2650010/1395342

Comment: how do I implement the comment in the above link?

Comment: "I am making a lockscreen" -- you are making an app that claims to be a lockscreen, but in reality reduces the user's security. The only way to really implement a "lockscreen" is as part of the operating system. All third-party lockscreens can be trivially defeated by rebooting in safe mode. And, since these third-party lockscreens ask the user to disable the OS's own lock screen security, you wind up with a less-secure device overall.

Comment: The users can see the security permissions and they know what they are getting into and a lockscreen is technically any app that locks a phone.I am not planning to offer pattern or password unlock

Answer (score 1):

Add this code in your `onCreate()` method before calling `setContentView()`

```
this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could intercept the HOME button via onKeyDown callback, and take appropriate action, but I'm not sure if it will work. Didn't tried myself.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
            // Do nothing, or everything else you want to do when the HOME is pressed.
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: I thought this was just keyboard keys.

Comment: This code along with the onAttachToWindow() code in my question can disable all the keys but not the notification bar....

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:name=".MyActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
```

instead

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
```