# At android : How can I Prevent the exit from the app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How can I Prevent the exit from the app, even when the user press on home button or back or recent Task button

I followed this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70913372/10733439

but there is an issue when I click on the Home button to close it, **it opens after 3 seconds automatically** and if I open another app before 3 seconds my app does not open

Comment: Stop messing with normal behavior! Your app will be banned :) There's no way to do this

Comment: @Demigod Yup, he shouldn't be messing with it at all (even though he should in some situations that he just doesn't have a choice or whatsoever). I made a disclaimer on my answer just to add that sprinkle of salt.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but what about if I put a password to exit from my app.!

Comment: @OsamaSayed That is a different question. I believe that you have to figure it out on your own.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.