# How to lock app in recent apps programmatically in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want the app to be unclosable. I noticed that it can be done if im pressing on the lock button in the recent app screen. Is there any way to lock it programmatically when the app is running?

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It's a bad user experience.

Comment: This app is for self-use only, the point is that i want that it will be hard to close the app. @PradeepSimha

Comment: Sometimes it switches to locking state spontaneous, immediately after installing from Play Market. I'm having it issue  approximately in 2% my app's installs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible to do.

That lock icon is a feature of whatever phone you are running, not built into Android.

Alternatively, you can use a foreground service to continuously check if your activity is open, and if it gets closed then re-open it.

Comment: Hey, thanks alot for the answer. Can you link me to a service that does that? Thanks. @Shmuel

Comment: Use this as an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18276355/how-to-keep-a-foreground-app-running-24-7

Comment: @Shmuel https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-make-use-of-the-android-nougat-recent-apps-lock/ according to this article lock recent apps is implemented since android nougat, I hope it means this is not phone specific but OS specific feature