# how to make my app open when the screen turns on in android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

When I open my screnn I want to make my app open.
It is password application and I want that EVERY time that the screnn open the app will ask the password.

I made all the code that i need for the app but it is not working and the app does not open.
I used RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED:

```
<user-permission android:name="android.intent.category.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application
  ...
   <receiver
      android:name="com.test.receiver"
      android:enabled="true" >
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
</application>
```

and here is the java part:

```
public class receiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
   {
      intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent); // context.startActivity(intent); does not work too
   }
}
```

i will be happy if someone will help me, and if someone can say too me how acn i cancel somehow the home button i will be thanksful a lot :)

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657300/disable-all-home-button-and-task-bar-features-on-nexus-7/16657359#16657359) for disabling the home button and starting an activity from a BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Though I think there may be a better way to achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other SO posts suggest you will need to use this code for your app to appear above the lock screen;

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON|
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD|
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED|
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

[Android activity over default lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629179/android-activity-over-default-lock-screen)

---

Further SO posts suggest you will need to do something like this so that you can unlock the phone with your application;

Permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>`

```
mKeyGuardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    mLock = mKeyGuardManager.newKeyguardLock("activity_classname");
    mLock.disableKeyguard();
```

[Lock the android device programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545079/lock-the-android-device-programatically) (Someone says that method is obsolete, but the [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/activity_testing.html#UnlockDevice) seem to disagree)

Comment: Just remember that if you use this method, it still will not work if the user has a password(pin,pattern,etc) it will not work as you cannot bypass it with the flags above.

Comment: so it will work after the password was typed? or it is just won't open?

Comment: The second part under the `<hr/>` was added to cover methods for bypassing the password.